# Create subset using select in R

Tags: sql, r, select, where-clause, sql-in

I am new to R scripting, I need to create subset of dataset using select function with some condition, I need just two columns not all columns.

This is my code

```
sqldf('SELECT * FROM dataset WHERE column1 IN (1, 0) AND column2 IN (9, 12)')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, `select *` gives you *all* columns (that's what the `*` stands for). If you just want *some* of them, then enumerate them in the `select` clause, like:

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM dataset WHERE column1 IN (1, 0) AND column2 IN (9, 12)
```

Comment: Thank u very much, I knew it was that easy but it is because I am new to SQL and R.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use very simple R-code below,

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
   dplyr::select(column1,column2)
```

Comment: OP might be talking about `SELECT` from the `SQL` language, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% select(col1, col2) %>% filter(col1= col1 %in% c(0,1), col2= col2 %in% c(9,12))
```